# How To Get Value From id Present In Table Data Of Table Using Jquery And Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here i have one partial view i.e _GetRelatedCommentList.
below is partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<ChaPMS.Core.Model.TaskAssignedDailyLog>


<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comments)
    </th>

</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)<br />


            <h4><small style="float:right;"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.UsrName)&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostedOn)</small></h4>

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.PercentCompleted, new { @id = "per" })
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Now on calling the partial view using ajax the data will consisting the above partial view, Now what i am trying to get the value from Id shown as below which is one of the td of table which is present in above partial view

```
<td>
   @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.PercentCompleted, new { @id = "per" })
</td>
```

Below is my success part of ajax where the problem lies, And the problem is in `var newPercentCompleted = $(data).find("#per").val();` where var newPercentCompleted is always undefined even after the data consists above partial view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateComment(data, status, xhr)
{       
    var newPercentCompletedContainer = $(this).closest("tr").find(".newPercentCompleted");
    var newPercentCompleted = $(data).find("#per").val();       
    $(newPercentCompletedContainer).html(newPercentCompleted);
}
```

Comment: having multiple elements with same id is invalid html and will cause issues as you are facing right now

Comment: from where the javascript function gets called?